# How make smooth scrolling in nuxt.js and bootstrap site?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I try make site with nuxt.js and [this template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/). I copied folders: css, img, js, scss, vendor from template to *static* folder of my nuxt project. After this I maked [nuxt.config.js](https://gist.github.com/tolyanor/fa602348bcc40d18a9a44a532e0bf22b) and [pages/index.vue](https://gist.github.com/tolyanor/b677669563b13498aff169e0fab9fa77) files. All working good except smooth scrolling on page. I see error in browser console:

```
agency.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at a (agency.min.js:7)
at agency.min.js:7
at agency.min.js:7
```

How I can resolve this issue?

UPD: You can [download](https://yadi.sk/d/v_xBsrVDUdscXQ) this project to reproduce error

Answer (score 19):

First, you need to overwrite the router default behavior like this. Paste this anywhere inside your nuxt.config.js:

```js
   {
     //.......
      router: {
        scrollBehavior(to) {
          if (to.hash) {
            return window.scrollTo({
              top: document.querySelector(to.hash).offsetTop + window.innerHeight,
              behavior: 'smooth'
            })
          }
          return window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
        }
      }
    }
```

Then your anchor link should be like this:

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/',hash:'#about'}">Contact</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: I don't know why no-one upvoted this answer. It's the only way I could get smooth scrolling with Nuxt. Be sure to turn off `html {scrolling: smooth}` in your css.

Comment: it really works and most effective way, you don't have to install any package which gives you more add kilobytes

Comment: In order to not clutter the `nuxt.config` is it possible to move this code to a plugin file?

Answer (score 14):

Sajjad Aljileezi's answer is valid, however, if you are looking for a simpler alternative is to add this simple line in a custom CSS file. You can import said file into your `nuxt.config.js` file.

```
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

The `nuxt.config.js` file would like something like this:

```
css: ['~/assets/style/yourcssfile.css']
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Nuxt v2.9.0, you can use a file to overwrite the router scrollBehavior. This file should be placed in ~/app/router.scrollBehavior.js (note: filename is case-sensitive if running on Windows).

Resources:

- [Nuxt Scroll Behavior file](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#scrollbehavior)
- [Modifying Vue.js Scroll Behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)

Here's an example with smooth scrolling to hash links, otherwise scrolling to top.

```
export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.hash) {
    return {
      selector: to.hash,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    }
  } else {
    return { x: 0, y: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the **server-side rendering**, you are using something that SSR  can't resolve, probably a call to window or document.

If you need to specify that you want to import a resource only on the client-side, you need to use the **process.client** variable.

You can check this out here : https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined

Answer (score 0):

It seems in nuxt 2.16+ for smooth scrolling basic setup

```
<button @click=scrollToTop()>Jump to top of page</button>
```

.
.
.

```
methods: {
    scrollToTop() {
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
    }
  }
```